# Exchanging route with navigate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to not pass a string as parameter.

```
<Button onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('test'); }} />
```

I can change the screen without passing a string. Is it possible to search for a route within the 'navigate' object?

Nothing found in the documentation.

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the route of your search?

Comment: Are you using typescript or javascript?

Comment: I'm using javascript

Comment: Ex: navigation.navigate(navigation.ROUTES.TEST);